# How to toggle binary / reader

Tags: pdf-tools

`M-x TeX-view` opens the binary of the generated pdf. I'm looking for the output. I used to know how to toggle between the two but I forgot. What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `TeX-View` has to do with this: I presume it just opens the PDF file and since you've tagged your question with `pdf-tools`, I presume it should open it using that.

The fact that it opens it literally probably means that there is no entry in `auto-mode-alist` to tell it what mode the file is in, so it opens it in `Fundamental` mode.

Check that there is an entry in `auto-mode-alist` that looks like this:  `("\\.[pP][dD][fF]\\'" . pdf-view-mode)`.

AFAICT, in `pdf-view-mode` you can type `C-c C-x` to switch to  `hexl-mode` and type `C-c C-x` again to switch back to `pdf-view-mode`. But that's probably not going to work in `Fundamental` mode.